# Error: The source filename are larger than is supported by the file system. Cannot delete files. Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8

[image]

I tried changing file name but it won't change. Tried moving and deleting. Tried deleting from cmd but it won't work.

Comment: @DavidPostill its not a dupkicate, i tried this answer but it also won't work, thats why i posted that question.

Comment: The second answer in that linked question is what I proposed. I hadn't seen it prior to answering though...

Comment: Then please next time you what you have already tried. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: @DavidPostill kindly read my description of the question your clearly see that what i have done before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember running into this problem before due to a failed backup. It took me hours of searching before I came across [this](http://www.anetforums.com/posts.aspx?ThreadIndex=12667) not-so-good solution (although it does work).

1. Create a new user account.
2. Move the file into that user account.
3. Delete the account.

Another solution from Microsoft [here.](http://support2.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081)

Users in same situation [here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/03882653-42e0-41d1-b3d5-d11609dacf37/cannot-delete-files-file-name-is-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows API (with some exceptions), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

However it is possible to create longer filenames, through a variety of means and that's what's happened here.

Fortunately unless you've specifically turned the option off, all files in Windows still have an 8.3 filename. This will have a ~ in it somewhere (e.g. in my system32 directory there's a file called {A6D608F0-0BDE-491A-97AE-5C4B05F7CDA2}.bat which has an 8.3 name of `{A6D60~1.BAT` (the first six characters of the filename, then a tilde, and then a number in case multiple files have the same first six characters).

- Open a command prompt (cmd.exe)
- Change to the relevant directory
- Get this using the dir /x command
- Then use that ~ filename to delete the file